# how to use <img> onError source as <div>

Tags: angular

i want to insert another url with onError function.

```
  '<div class="item"
      style="content:url(https://itemimage.jpg)" alt="No Product Image" ></div>'
```

in here i want to insert default  div background content:url if the image is not found or in case of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content URL is on the CSS side, and will not raise any event to JS side at all. A similar approach with onError can be like this:

```html
<div style="content:url(https://example.com/what.jpg)" alt="No Product Image" >
  <img style="display: none" src="https://example.com/what.jpg" onerror="this.parentElement.style.content = 'url(https://placehold.it/300x300)'">
</div>
```

But IMO it is weird to do div with content style, why not just use `<img>` then.

Comment: Thank you very much .  Its working for my code. According to the situation i can't use <img> tag .  Thats why i used this <div> tag.

Comment: i used this method before . but i unable to use correct path for onerror="this.parentElement.style.content = 'url(https://placehold.it/300x300)'"   this.

Comment: what an interesting situation. always mind the relative and absolute pathing ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code worked:

```
<div class="item" style="background-image: url('/images/bg.jpg'), url('/images/altbg.jpeg');"></div>
```

The first image "bg.jpeg" is the background image I want to use, if it's not available it will use "altbg.jpeg" as the background image. The bg.jpeg can be an image from the database for example.